# How would I make a player take damage when they're looking at another player

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-education-edition

I am playing a Minecraft: Education Edition world and I want to make it so 1 player is the monster and the rest are runners. The ideal result would be the monster turns invisible then reappears in front of another player and then while that player is looking at the monster while not invisible they take damage and are slowed. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @pinckerman correct

Comment: hi, may i know if you can use datapacks in bedrock/ educational edi?

Comment: @hfanatic in a way, it's simalar to bedrock but we are stuck in 1.17.31.2

Comment: If this was in Java it would be a lot easier to mod and use datapacks. You would probably have to get a datapack or mod to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Generic Looking-At detection

[Answer taken from this wiki article.](https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/wiki/questions/lookat/)

### 1.19.50 and above

Once Education edition reaches version 1.19.50+ (at the time of writing it is still on 1.18.40), it should get the "new" execute syntax which can make a "what am I looking at" detection a lot easier. Or well, at least use less commands because this one command is quite long and complex. See the link above for a breakdown of what it does and how it works.

generic command:

```
execute as @a at @s anchored eyes facing <entity / coordinates> anchored feet positioned ^ ^ ^1 rotated as @s positioned ^ ^ ^-1 if entity @s[distance=..0.1] run ...
```

command for this usecase:

```
execute as @a at @s anchored eyes facing entity @a[tag=monster] eyes anchored feet positioned ^ ^ ^1 rotated as @s positioned ^ ^ ^-1 if entity @s[distance=..0.1] run effect @s slowness
```

### 1.19.40 and below

You can either try to recreate the above command using multiple steps to mimic the new execute (see link above for details). However due to how rotations work in bedrock, this will probably not work as well as it could.

## Question specific detection

In this case, you can **check for whether the monster is X amount of blocks in front of the player.** Using local coordinates (`^ ^ ^`) that is fairly easy in 1.19.50 and above. So, for example using these commands in a repeating commandblock chain, you'd give everyone who is looking at the monster player (up to 5 blocks away) slowness.

```
tag @a remove lookingAtMonster
execute as @a at @s positioned ^ ^ ^1 if entity @a[tag=monster] run tag @s add lookingAtMonster
execute as @a at @s positioned ^ ^ ^2 if entity @a[tag=monster] run tag @s add lookingAtMonster
execute as @a at @s positioned ^ ^ ^3 if entity @a[tag=monster] run tag @s add lookingAtMonster
execute as @a at @s positioned ^ ^ ^4 if entity @a[tag=monster] run tag @s add lookingAtMonster 
execute as @a at @s positioned ^ ^ ^5 if entity @a[tag=monster] run tag @s add lookingAtMonster
effect @a[tag=lookingAtMonster] slowness
```

For the older execute that would be a little more difficult to achieve, as you cannot just test for entities that way. One possible workaround could be, depending on the circumstances, to set a specific block under the the monsters feet, and then using

```
execute @a ^ ^ ^1 detect ~ ~-1 ~ <specific block> run tag @s add lookingAtMonster
```

Remember to set the block back to what it was afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a proximity detection so that if the runner is close to the monster while the monster is visible it will do the blindness and damage. You can create the proximity detection by using the */testforplayer* command and x y z dx dy dz to test a specific location and then have a comparator going out of the command block and into another one that will provide slowness and poison to the player.

Comment: This could do with more details. **How** does one make a "proximity detection" (sic)? That's basically what the question is asking

Comment: with a /testforplayer command using x y z dx dy dz to test a specific block then use a comparator to activate another command block if there is a player there.

Comment: So add that via an [edit] to the answer.

Comment: There is that better.